# Using AngularJs and ES6 Class: 'this' is not available in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-class

I'm confused about how ES6 Class and AngularJs work together.

NOTE: The following is a pseudo code to illustrate the confusion, it was never tested

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="x in list">
  <div ng-click='clickMe(x)'>click</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
class TstController {

  constructor() {
    this.someVar = 'value';
  }
  clickMe() {
    alert(this.someVar) //someVar is undefined
  }
}
```

The problem is that in clickMe, `this == ChildScope` therefore someVar is undefined,

My question is how do I pass the TstController `this` reference to clickMe?

Comment: It should work.. how you're calling `clickMe`?

Comment: Please post relevant HTML or provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using ES6 `class`, I'd recommend you to use `controllerAs` syntax. Eventually it will expose class context(`this`) on view via controller alias. So whatever available inside your controller class that will be available on view with the help of its alias like here I used `tst.list` & `tst.clickMe` on HTML.

**Html**

```
<body ng-controller="TstController as tst">
  <div ng-repeat="x in tst.list">
    <div ng-click='tst.clickMe(x)'>click</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gEIyYTnaUJdt3kQJp6pU?p=preview)

Comment: @EliaWeiss -- This is the correct way of using ES6 classes with AngularJS. Don't mess with `$scope` anymore, since you have a cleaner way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare it before constructor. And call using this.

```
class Tst {
      someVar:any; // this line is missing
      constructor() {
        this.someVar = 'value';
      }
      clickMe() {
        alert(this.someVar) //someVar is undefined
      }
    }
```

Comment: No, that will not be a valid syntax with ES6 classes. Its valid only TS.

Answer (score 0):

In Tst constructor I did `$scope.self = this;`

I inspected the 'this' object in Chrome Dev Console and found that I can get the value of someVar with the following

```
this.$parent.$parent.self.someVar
```

in `clickMe`

NOTE: 'this' is not set to 'x', it is set to ChildScope

Comment: Something is wrong here.. Can you create plunker with problem statement, I'll be more than happy to help you :)

Comment: you are correct, I need to do `this.$scope.self = this`